# Merging two dataframes of different sizes, as per some condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**SOLVED**
(see comment by Unbridledscum below)

I am currently attempting to join the information of two dataframes together.

My initial dataframe contains the product ID (SKU_id) as well as the product name as follows:

(Pardon the truncation of SKU_id)

```
df
Out[127]: 
          SKU_id          Product Name
0   7.336012e+09  OLD STYLE BEER      
1   1.820001e+09  BUDWEISER BEER LONG 
2   1.820000e+09  BUDWEISER BEER      
3   3.410018e+09  MILLER GENUINE DRAFT
4   3.410018e+09  MILLER GENUINE DRAFT
5   8.066096e+09  CORONA EXTRA BEER NR
```

My other dataframe contains all other product information such as unit sales etc (As well as SKU_id).

```
data.head()
Out[159]: 
       Store_id      SKU_id  WEEK  Units_Sold  QTY  PRICE Promotion 
20462  5         1820000016  166   1           1    3.79   NaN        
20463  5         1820000016  167   3           1    3.79   NaN        
20464  5         1820000016  168   6           1    3.79   NaN        
20465  5         1820000016  169   2           1    3.79   NaN        
20466  5         1820000016  170   1           1    3.79   NaN
```

I now want to join these two dataframes. More specifically I want to add the name of the particular SKU_id, which is present in the first dataframe (df) and not the second (data).

Both dataframes include the particular SKU_id's. I want to find a way to look at what the SKU_id is in the second dataframe (data) and then add the corresponding name from the first dataframe (df)

The output I am looking for is something like this:

```
       Store_id      SKU_id  WEEK  Units_Sold  QTY  PRICE Promotion  Product Name
20462  5         1820000016  166   1           1    3.79   NaN       BUDWEISER BEER LONG  
20463  5         1820000016  167   3           1    3.79   NaN       BUDWEISER BEER LONG  
20464  5         1820000016  168   6           1    3.79   NaN       BUDWEISER BEER LONG  
20465  5         1820000016  169   2           1    3.79   NaN       BUDWEISER BEER LONG  
20466  5         1820000016  170   1           1    3.79   NaN       BUDWEISER BEER LONG
```

The problem is the two dataframes are of different sizes and I have no clue how to code a way to look at the SKU_id and add the corresponding name.
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where `df1` dataframe from your question and `df2` is the second that you have provided

```
for i,val in enumerate(df2['SKU_id']):
    df2.loc[i,"Product"]=df1.loc[df['SKU_id'] ==val, 'Product Name'].iloc[0]
df2.head()
```

`Dataframe1` that I used as an example:

```
    SKU_id      Product Name
0   7336012000  OLD STYLE BEER
1   1820000016  BUDWEISER BEER LONG
```

`Dataframe2` that I used as an example:

```
 Store_id   SKU_id
0   5   1820000016
1   5   1820000016
2   5   7336012000
```

This will give you something  like:

```
 Store_id   SKU_id  Product
0   5   1820000016  BUDWEISER BEER LONG
1   5   1820000016  BUDWEISER BEER LONG
2   5   7336012000  OLD STYLE BEER
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to do two things here, but not necessarily in this order:

1. Merge the two tables
2. Filter on the SKU

So you need something like this.

```
data.merge(df, how="left").query('SKU_id == 12345')
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but how would this work if i specify for a particular SKU. I want this to work for each and every SKU in the data table. As such using query('SKU_id == 12345') limits the possibility to only one SKU? Sorry if i am misunderstanding your code

Comment: I do however believe the answer lies in using .merge(). I am just unsure as to how.

Comment: data.merge(df, how="left") joins the two tables (left join just in case you are missing SKU_ids in the 2nd table).

It is smart enough to recognise that SKU_id is in both tables and will try to merge on all matching columns.

Otherwise you would need something like data.merge(df, how="left", left_on="SKU_id", right_on="sku").

Point is, if you want to look at another SKU just change the ID part. And if you want to look at ALL SKUs then just erase the query() part.

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin function in pandas to do exactly what you're looking for:

[.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
data = data.merge(df, how = 'left', on = 'SKU_id')
```

Comment: Thanks. This is in effect as mentioned by Unbridledscum in another comment. Works perfectly thanks

Answer (score 1):

new_df = pd.merge(data, df, how = 'left', on = 'SKU_id')
Try this this may help